# MemoryError during numpy array assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I am taking data for an experiment that returns 8 bit numpy arrays, but need to convert that into floats for the data.  I keep running into MemryErrors at two points in my code.  The whole code is substantial, but I have put what I think are the important parts here.  The MemoryError does not occur every time, but rather after many loops of the experiment.  Unfortunately for now I am stuck with 32 bit python, which I know has memory limits.  `c` is a dictionary.

```py
def configure_buffers(self, c):
    if 'buffer' in c:
        del c['buffer']
        gc.collect()
    c['buffer'] = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.float32)

def aquire_data(self, c):
    buffer = c['buffer']
    records = get_data()   # this a numpy array with dtype=np.uint8
    buffer[...] = records.astype(np.float32)
    # operations to buffer
    c['buffer'] = buffer   # I don't think this is actually necessary
```

The first place I sometimes get an error is when I use `np.empty` to allocate a buffer.  I tried to prevent this by deleting any old buffer (sometimes of a different size, that's why it needs to be reallocated) before the allocation, but this doesn't seem to always help.

The second time I run into trouble is when I fill the buffer with `buffer[...] = ...`.  Unfortunately using `copy=False` in the `astype()` does not help because it is converting from 8 bits to 32 and cannot do so in place.  Is this MemoryError arising because it creates the array in memory before assigning it to the buffer, such that I have double the size of the array in memory at a time?  Is there a better way to assign this in order to avoid this?

Are there better ways of dealing with any of this?  Any tips for dealing with large arrays?  Thanks!

Comment: `buffer[...] = records.astype(np.float32)` yes, the new array produced by `astype` will live in memory at the same time as whatever is in `buffer`. The right hand side of this assignment is *fully evaluated* before `buffer.__setitem(..., <rhs>)` is called. Are you always doing `buffer[...] = `? why not simply `del c['buffer']; c['buffer'] = get_data().astype(np.float32)`?

Comment: I tried that too and still got memory errors, unfortunately.

Comment: How big are your arrays? Are you sure you can even expect to keep them inmemory? What is the `shape` you are working with?

Comment: They vary in size, and the frequency with which I get the errors seems to scale with size.  With arrays of 15k*2*1024 I see the errors every five minutes or so.

Comment: If you are operating so close to the memory limit, or the arrays are so large, it is hard to fine tune the memory usage.  Also simply deleting a buffer doesn't free up the space.  You might have referenced it under some other variable or list, or make a `view` (or slice).